# How to pass a function to constructor

Tags: perl

How to pass a function to constructor, so the class could use it internally?

**test.pl**

```
use Class;
use Loger;

my $loger = Loger->new();
$loger->log('I have logger now, I can log messages!');

my $class = Class->new(\&{ $loger->log }); # here we pass the function (the method of other class) to contructor of a new  Class

$class->do_something();  # class uses loger->log internally to report errors
```

**Class.pm**
    package Class;

```
sub new {

    my $self = {};
    $self->{log} = shift; # we got logger->log function, save it for future use

    return bless $self;
}

sub do_something {
     my $self = shift;

     open_file or $self->{log}->('Cant open file'); # we can use gotten logger in class 
}


1;
```

Comment: You may want to look into using a singleton pattern for this: http://perldesignpatterns.com/?SingletonPattern . Each class that needs to use the logger could call, e.g. Logger::getLogger() (or just Logger->new()) instead of taking it as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there.

While `$loger->log` is a function invocation, you can use `\&Loger::log` to reference the function.

`\&{ref($loger)."::log"}` might work as well.

Incorporating @simbabques point, you should *curry* your function before passing it, i.e. pre-providing the first argument. You can do this by calling the constructor with

```
sub {$loger->log(@_)}
```

or

```
sub {unshift @_, $loger; goto \&Loger::log} # more efficient
```

as argument.

Comment: The `sub {$loger->log(@_)}` example creates a closure, right? The second one is just weird and doesn't look like it should be used in production code without a serious block of comments.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, both are closures (all `sub`s are), and the second one breaches OOP (`Loger` cannot be a subclass). But it has the advantage of saving a little memory and it runs ~ twice as fast because of the (evil) `goto` and method resolution is skipped ;-)

Comment: This kind of `goto` is not as evil as the other sort. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a method, not a function (or sub). Calling it on its own will not work. If you want an object's method, pass the object and call the method on the object.

```
my $loger = Loger->new();
$loger->log('I have logger now, I can log messages!');

my $class = Class->new(logger => $loger); # pass the Loger object
```

And in `Class.pm`:

```
package Class;

sub new
{
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  my $self = {};
  $self->{log} = $args{'logger'}; # store it inside your Class object
  return bless $self;
}

sub do_something
{
   my $self = shift;
   open_file or $self->{log}->log->('Cant open file'); # call its log-method
}
```

Comment: thank you, I know this way , but  "$self->{log}->log->('Cant open file')" looks ugly

Comment: @xoid, then abstract it away!  Write a method `$self->log()` which calls `$self->{log}->log()` for you, or doesn't if `$self->{log}` isn't a valid logger.

Comment: @xoid: What @pilcow says, plus store it in `$self->{'LoggerInstance'}` or similar, so that it is more selfexplanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` referencing operator only works on named symbols.

Your line:

`my $class = Class->new(\&{ $loger->log });`

is actually an attempt to pass an *anonymous* subroutine. It is also missing a way to pass the parameters to $loger->log().

You can change it to ths:

`my $class = Class->new(sub { $loger->log(@_) });`